# Keyboard macro program for OS X

Tags: macos, software-rec, automation, macros

I am after a program to complete a series of key presses automatically, with next to no involvement from a human.

Basicly, I want it to hold down the spacebar, whilst pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> a couple of times, then <kbd>T</kbd> a couple of times, then loop until I stop it manually.

Is it possible to do this? Can I use Apple Script, or would I have to resort to another program.

Answer (score 3):

This should be entirely possible with AppleScript alone.

The basic loop structure is:

```
repeat

/* your code goes here... */

end repeat
```

to send keystrokes, you can use `keystroke`:

```
tell application "Application Name Here"
    keystroke "A"
end tell
```

this would send a capital "a" to a specific running application.

If you wanted to send a key while holding another down:

```
tell application "Application Name Here"
    keystroke "A" using {command down}
end tell
```

this would send an "a" while holding down the command key.

There is an excellent plethora of information available about AppleScript on [Mac OSX Automation](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/learn.html).

Comment: I keep getting "<program name> got an error: Can’t get keystroke "a".". What gives?

Comment: You may have entered the incorrect application name. Try using `System Events` as the application name.

Comment: doesn't work for me neither

Answer (score 2):

I've tried Automator and it's not the easiest thing to do if you're looking to move beyond your immediate request.

If you're willing to try a 3rd-party program, [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) is incredibly powerful and easy to use. I installed it and had my keyboard shortcuts running in no time.

One nice thing about KM is that you can create simple text-based shortcuts, so that you don't have to take your hands off the keyboard to use the macro. I'm a developer and use vim and the command-line extensively so not having to use any special keys is important to me.

So, in my case... I created a macro that was invoked with ',,,sign' which entered my testing user id, tabbed to the next field, entered the password, tabbed to the next field, entered the [Enter] key and - voila! - I am signed in.

Simple and incredibly effective. It's not free; after a trial period, you have to purchase it, but it was a no-brainer for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use [quicksilver](https://qsapp.com/index.php) - install it, create a text file with the keystrokes you want, and then create a "custom trigger" and assign it a hotkey.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: 404 on the link. points to blacktree.com with a google 404 page :/